Folium Error: Object of type CustomIcon is not JSON serializable
I am creating an interactive map in Folium.
I am trying to set a Custom icon from my local disc (.svg or .png).
### Filepaths

fp1 = r"filepath.shp"

#Specify icon filepath
icon_home = folium.CustomIcon("house-svgrepo-com.svg")

#Read a file:
points = gpd.read_file(fp1)


#Create an empty map
map = folium.Map(
    location=[53.23, 23.15],
    # tiles="cartodb positron",
    zoom_start=12,
    control_scale=True)
    
#Add a point layer to a map
points_gjson = folium.features.GeoJson(
    points,
    icon=icon_home,
    name="Near municipalities").add_to(map)
    
    
map.save(outputfilepath.html)

map

But during trying to accomplish this I receive an error:
File c:\Users\Kuba\.conda\envs\iFOS\Lib\site-packages\folium\elements.py:25, in JSCSSMixin.render(self, **kwargs)
     22 for name, url in self.default_css:
     23     figure.header.add_child(CssLink(url), name=name)
---> 25 super().render(**kwargs)

File c:\Users\Kuba\.conda\envs\iFOS\Lib\site-packages\branca\element.py:685, in MacroElement.render(self, **kwargs)
    682     figure.script.add_child(Element(script(self, kwargs)), name=self.get_name())
    684 for name, element in self._children.items():
--> 685     element.render(**kwargs)

File c:\Users\Kuba\.conda\envs\iFOS\Lib\site-packages\folium\features.py:803, in GeoJson.render(self, **kwargs)
    801     if self.highlight:
    802         self.highlight_map = mapper.get_highlight_map(self.highlight_function)
--> 803 super().render()

File c:\Users\Kuba\.conda\envs\iFOS\Lib\site-packages\folium\map.py:62, in Layer.render(self, **kwargs)
     54 if self.show:
     55     self.add_child(
     56         ElementAddToElement(
     57             element_name=self.get_name(),
   (...)
     60         name=self.get_name() + "_add",
     61     )
---> 62 super().render(**kwargs)

File c:\Users\Kuba\.conda\envs\iFOS\Lib\site-packages\branca\element.py:682, in MacroElement.render(self, **kwargs)
    680 script = self._template.module.__dict__.get("script", None)
    681 if script is not None:
--> 682     figure.script.add_child(Element(script(self, kwargs)), name=self.get_name())
    684 for name, element in self._children.items():
    685     element.render(**kwargs)

File c:\Users\Kuba\.conda\envs\iFOS\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\runtime.py:763, in Macro.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    757 elif len(args) > self._argument_count:
    758     raise TypeError(
    759         f"macro {self.name!r} takes not more than"
    760         f" {len(self.arguments)} argument(s)"
    761     )
--> 763 return self._invoke(arguments, autoescape)

File c:\Users\Kuba\.conda\envs\iFOS\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\runtime.py:777, in Macro._invoke(self, arguments, autoescape)
    774 if self._environment.is_async:
    775     return self._async_invoke(arguments, autoescape)  # type: ignore
--> 777 rv = self._func(*arguments)
    779 if autoescape:
    780     rv = Markup(rv)

File <template>:230, in macro(l_1_this, l_1_kwargs)

File c:\Users\Kuba\.conda\envs\iFOS\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\filters.py:1688, in do_tojson(eval_ctx, value, indent)
   1685     kwargs = kwargs.copy()
   1686     kwargs["indent"] = indent
-> 1688 return htmlsafe_json_dumps(value, dumps=dumps, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\Kuba\.conda\envs\iFOS\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\utils.py:658, in htmlsafe_json_dumps(obj, dumps, **kwargs)
    654 if dumps is None:
    655     dumps = json.dumps
    657 return markupsafe.Markup(
--> 658     dumps(obj, **kwargs)
    659     .replace("<", "\\u003c")
    660     .replace(">", "\\u003e")
    661     .replace("&", "\\u0026")
    662     .replace("'", "\\u0027")
    663 )

File c:\Users\Kuba\.conda\envs\iFOS\Lib\json\__init__.py:238, in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    232 if cls is None:
    233     cls = JSONEncoder
    234 return cls(
    235     skipkeys=skipkeys, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii,
    236     check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    237     separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
--> 238     **kw).encode(obj)

File c:\Users\Kuba\.conda\envs\iFOS\Lib\json\encoder.py:200, in JSONEncoder.encode(self, o)
    196         return encode_basestring(o)
    197 # This doesn't pass the iterator directly to ''.join() because the
    198 # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    199 # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 200 chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    201 if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    202     chunks = list(chunks)

File c:\Users\Kuba\.conda\envs\iFOS\Lib\json\encoder.py:258, in JSONEncoder.iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    253 else:
    254     _iterencode = _make_iterencode(
    255         markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent, floatstr,
    256         self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    257         self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 258 return _iterencode(o, 0)

File c:\Users\Kuba\.conda\envs\iFOS\Lib\json\encoder.py:180, in JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
    161 def default(self, o):
    162     """Implement this method in a subclass such that it returns
    163     a serializable object for ``o``, or calls the base implementation
    164     (to raise a ``TypeError``).
   (...)
    178 
    179     """
--> 180     raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o .__class__.__name__} '
    181                     f'is not JSON serializable')

**TypeError: Object of type CustomIcon is not JSON serializable**

The error:
TypeError: Object of type CustomIcon is not JSON serializable
I tried different filepaths "path\filename"/"filename", used the different icon formats, but could not find a similar solution.
Related issues:
https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/user_guide/ui_elements/icons.html
